# Apple отклоняет приложение, ссылаясь на пункт 3.1.1

Tags: apple, appstore

Есть проблема Apple отклоняет приложение, говоря что мое приложение использует механизм подписок отличающиеся от In-App Purchase API. Используется официальный StoreKit от Apple. [введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lxGr.jpg)

Comment: С какой целью сообщаешь тут об этом?

Answer (score 1):

Как можно понять - в приложении реализована система подписки или внутриигровых покупок. По правилам appstore, механизм этих подписок и покупок должны быть реализован по их схеме. Тебе написали -  читай guideline 3.1.3 Review Guidelines

Comment: Подписка сделана полностью на официальном API Apple, и соблюдены требования Apple